# Using MarkLogic to counting

Tags: nosql, marklogic, xquery-sql

> I am a beginner in the field of MarkLogic and need help in solving
>   this question with clarification please. This is an example of xml
>   classes. I need a function to count the number of classes a student
>   attends, use map

```
<Classes>
   <Class>
      <Class-name>math</Class-name>
      <Student-name>Jon</Student-name>
      <Student-name>Sam</Student-name>
   </Class>
   <Class>
     <Class-name>Sciences</Class-name>
     <Student-name>Jon</Student-name>
     <Student-name>Jack</Student-name>
     <Student-name>Nay</Student-name>
   </Class>
   <Class>
     <Class-name>Languages</Class-name>
     <Student-name>Jon</Student-name>
     <Student-name>Sam</Student-name>
     <Student-name>Nay</Student-name>
   </Class>
</Classes>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to count without maps would be to collect a distinct list of `Student-name`, and then use those names to get a count of the `Student-name` elements with those names:

```
for $student in fn:distinct-values($Classes/Class/Student-name)
return 
  $student||":"||count($Classes/Class[Student-name=$student])
```

A way to achieve the same thing with maps would be to walk over each of the `Student-name` elements, putting an entry in the map that increments the current count by 1:

```
let $stats := map:new()
let $_ := 
  for $student in $Classes/Class/Student-name
  return map:put($stats, $student, 1 + (map:get($stats, $student), 0)[1])
return
  map:keys($stats) ! ( .||":"||map:get($stats, .) )
```

Comment: Thank you, I have a question can you tell me what to do these (map:get($stats, $student), 0)[1])

Comment: The expression: `(map:get($stats, $student), 0)[1]` attempts to get the current value from the map for that `$student` (there won't be a value the first time) and the number 0, and then uses a predicate to select the first item from that sequence of numbers. If there is a value for that $student, it uses it. Otherwise, it selects the number 0.